# SSRS 2008 R2 / 2012 Width Property Unit of Measure Default Setting

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Is there a way to configure the default unit of measure for the width / height properties used  to size cells / rows?

If I add a table and configure the width of the columns to a value specified in "pt" rather than "cm" I have to change them all as I specify the width (I am using pt to get over the inexplicable inability of SSRS to correctly align columns when exported to Excel).

Is there a way I can change from cm to pt as the default value for all measures in a report?

Comment: It wouldn't be too painful to write code that goes through the .rdl file and converts existing measurements. The .rdl is nicely formatted XML.

Comment: I suppose not - just seems rubbish not to have a built in solution. Mind you - it is madness that Microsoft haven't sorted out the Excel export issues yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imperial or metric, as I understand, is simply based on the windows regional setting.  Further customization of the default past that isn't currently possible.

I've seen one work around that [modifies the report template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bimusings/archive/2005/12/06/500462.aspx) which can potentially make your life easier but this approach has limitations as well.

Looking through Microsoft connect I don't see this posted yet as a feature request.  It seems to me that this would be an excellent suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for this. I might well suggest it - along with the Excel export being fixed!