# How to stop report altering width values after previewing / saving or set default unit

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've got several reports that need to be exported to excel. When I do so occasionally some cells are merged and some columns are hidden. I'm aware of this issue and the work-arounds. However, when using 1 of the work arounds (convert widths to pt) and aligning all fields with a column I still seem to get hidden columns / merging.

When I go back into the document after it's been saved it now shows the widths in cm's again rather than points. Is this because there is a default unit being used somewhere? If so how can I change this to pt?

I don't think that my new pt values are being converted back to cm's necessarily, but are simply showing a rounded cm value. However, it makes it frustrating / difficult to identify where the problem lies.

Any help would be appreciated.

***UPDATE***

I found this question relating to this but it doesn't answer categorically if this is possible or not. [SSRS 2008 R2 / 2012 Width Property Unit of Measure Default Setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750257/ssrs-2008-r2-2012-width-property-unit-of-measure-default-setting)

Comment: Merged cells are usually due to misalignment of the header and table cells. Can you strip off the header [as described in my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048363/ssrs-2005-set-simplepageheaders-on-the-report-instead-of-the-server/3058576#3058576)?

Comment: @ChrisLätta - Unfortunately stripping out the header cells is not an option as these are fundamental to the report. It's more a question of whether I can make alignment easier by defaulting to pt rather than cm. Also, it seems to sometimes add a random .00003 on the end of some column widths even if I've just typed in 50pt (comes out 50.00003pt). I've got a workaround, but wondering if this could be stopped as well.

Comment: I have had the issue of the designer adding random small lengths to cell lengths for no obvious reason. I found that editing the XML directly made the lengths stick to the values I wanted; however, I wasn't shifting between pt and cm so not sure it would help in your instance.

Comment: I've resolved the issue with the merged cells / blank columns (couple of header cells had 0.00003pt added on, which I'd missed). My workaround (rather than editing the xml directly) is to go to enter the next highest pt value e.g. if I enter 57pt and it turns into 57.00003pt I simply enter 58pt, hit enter, then change it to 57pt and it stays as is (no .00003pt). Strange, but it seems to work.